# How can I update my Python operator to be able to change input post-execution?

Tags: python, scripting

I am a beginner in blender scripting working on an addon that arrays an object radially. I want to still be able to change input post-execution. How?

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Radial Array",
    "author": "Gene Kristian",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > New Object",
    "description": "Arrays an object around a central point.",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy

from bpy.props import (IntProperty)

from bpy.types import(
    AddonPreferences,
    Operator,
    Panel,
    PropertyGroup,
)

class OBJECT_OT_radial_array(Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.radial_array"
    bl_label = "Radial Array"
    bl_description = "Arrays an object around a central point."
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    array_degree = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name = "Array Rotation",
        default = 0.523599,
        min = 0.1,
        max = 3,
        description = "Degree of rotation of the array.",
        subtype = "ANGLE",
    )
    array_count = bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "Array Count",
        default = 12,
        min = 4,
        max = 48,
        description = "Number of objects to array.",
    )
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object.select_get() and context.object.type == 'MESH' or context.object.type == 'CURVE'

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def execute(self, context):

        #selecting the target object, renaming it, and moving it from its origin.
        bpy.context.object.name = "Object"
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(5, 0, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

        #adding an empty xyz axis as the orbiting object.
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', location=(0, 0, 0))

        #changing the target object into the active.
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects['Object']

        #adding the array modifier.
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='ARRAY')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"].use_object_offset = True
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"].relative_offset_displace[0] = 0
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"].count = self.array_count
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"].offset_object = bpy.data.objects["Empty"]
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value= self.array_degree, orient_axis='Z', orient_type='GLOBAL')
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(OBJECT_OT_radial_array.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_radial_array)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_radial_array)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```